# opencv compiled programs: traincascade

Tags: opencv

Where is the opencv_traincascade compiled program stored on ubuntu? I can run the program opencv_traincascade from anywhere, but can't find where that program is. I want to insert some debug commands to deal with an issue I am haivng with traincascade. I can find traincascade.cpp, which I believe is the source code this program.

Thank you

Comment: So, basically are you asking "How do I find files on Linux"? I think that this problem already has a definitive solution somewhere on the web.

Comment: Actually, I found it. That suggestion on looking up how to find files in general on linux helped. Thank you.

Comment: Check: home/{OpencvDirectory}/build/bin